# Can I use a FutureBuilder with a value of the type FutureOr<T>?

Tags: flutter, future, flutter-futurebuilder

I was wondering if there is a way how I can use a `Future Builder` together with a `FutureOr<T>` typed `future`-parameter?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to always convert the `FutureOr<T>` to a `Future<T>`.  [The `Future` class](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Future-class.html) has numerous constructors that can do that:

- [`Future<T>.new`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Future/Future.html)
- [`Future<T>.microtask`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Future/Future.microtask.html)
- [`Future<T>.sync`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Future/Future.sync.html)
- [`Future<T>.value`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Future/Future.value.html)

Any of them should work, but if I'd use `Future<T>.value` or `Future<T>.new`:

```dart
FutureBuilder(future: Future.value(maybeFuture), ...)
```

If that isn't desirable (waiting on a `Future<T>` created from an existing `T` entails an extra iteration of the event loop), then it's pretty simple to create your own `FutureOrBuilder` widget that's like a `FutureBuilder` but that invokes its `AsyncWidgetBuilder` callback synchronously if possible:

```dart
class FutureOrBuilder<T> extends StatelessWidget {
  final FutureOr<T>? futureOrValue;

  final T? initialData;

  final AsyncWidgetBuilder<T> builder;

  const FutureOrBuilder({
    super.key,
    FutureOr<T>? future,
    this.initialData,
    required this.builder,
  }) : futureOrValue = future;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final futureOrValue = this.futureOrValue;
    if (futureOrValue is T) {
      return builder(
        context,
        AsyncSnapshot.withData(ConnectionState.done, futureOrValue),
      );
    } else {
      return FutureBuilder(
        future: futureOrValue,
        initialData: initialData,
        builder: builder,
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The issue with this is, that it will init a loading sequence even if the value is already present.

Comment: @Paul Have you observed that?  If I use a `Future.value` with `FutureBuilder`, I don't see the initial data rendered, although possibly I'm being lucky (or being unlucky and dropping a frame).  But if it's actually a problem, I've updated my answer to provide a way to synchronously build when possible.

Comment: Yes, I think Flutter might always start with a loading state, and if rendering is too slow (many loadings or heavy visuals) it will actually first build in a loading state and only later rebuild it. But your new solution is great! The flutter team should do this a default!!!